# What is the purpose of the tag '04182016 (that I believe was automatically added to my question)?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

On my recent question [Export Javascript source block to script tag in HTML when exporting Org file to HTML](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/28301/export-javascript-source-block-to-script-tag-in-html-when-exporting-org-file-to) the tag ['04182016](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/04182016) suddenly and misteriously appeared. I believe it happened automatically (that is, I believe I didn't add it myself --and I am sure I didn't add it *intentionally*). What triggered it? What does it mean? Why does it look like a date but not today's date?

(By the way, meta forces me to choose for this question between the tags 'discussion, 'feature-request, 'bug, 'support --none seems completely appropriate; I went with 'bug because "I found [...] unexpected behaviour in the system [...]". Feel free to retag it more appropriately.)

Comment: No idea.  Leave the tag on there for a bit in case anyone else knows what happened, and then we should probably just get rid of it.

Comment: Did you attempt to modify the tags in [revision 5](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/posts/28301/revisions), which is where the tag is recorded to have been added? Could this have been an accidental paste from a misplaced key press or click? What client (browser or app version, OS) did you use to post this revision?

Comment: I think I did not attempt to edit the tags at all, @Gilles. But I may have done so inadvertently. I really don't think I had anything remotely like 04182016 in my clipboard (or kill-ring see below), but I won't swear I didn't. I, um, don't remember how I made that edit, there are four possibilities: Firefox 45.4 on a Red Hat 4.8.5 machine, Microsoft Edge on a Windows 10 machine or the sx.el Emacs client from within Emacs 24.5 (on either of those two computers).

Comment: It doesn't look like there's going to be much more discussion, so I went ahead and deleted the tag.